# Find ASP.Net projectdir programmatically

Tags: asp.net

the title is my question. i don't know the details of the web server that my project will be deployed on. in one class i execute a batch file in the project directory. should i just say "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\etcetcetc" and hope for the best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Server.MapPath(ResolveUrl("~/"))
```